# Adding HTML to an SVG and flipping it in IE 10+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am looking at various ways to animate a graphic I have in SVG but I need things to work also in IE 10+.

I have an SVG polygon (or path) which is a hexagon and I want to be able to click on it and flip it over (on the x-axis where 0,0 is the center of the hexagon) and then scale that flipped hexagon to 2x its size. I then want to add HTML to it.

To recap:

1. Create a polygon/hexagon (did this).
2. Click on polygon to trigger an event.
3. Flip the polygon over on x-axis.
4. Scale flipped polygon to 2x and add HTML to it.

Is this indeed possible considering I need it to work in IE 10 or better?

Comment: to recap - show your code if you want your code fixed

Comment: Does the HTML need to be added to the SVG as a child or does it just need to render as though the SVG hexagon surrounds the HTML content?

Comment: It does not need to render as a child as I cannot get foreignOject to work in IE 10. So it can overlay but it would be so cool if it could render inside the hexagon's borders but not sure if that is possible.